# Assign a keymap to "Extract to arb file" bulb proposition

Tags: android-studio, flutter-plugin

I frequently use the option "Extract to ARB File" on the bulb to quick add translations:
[image]

Is there a way to assign a keymap to this useful function ?

And more generally, is there a way to assign keymap to bulb functions of Android Studio ?